# Check Textarea Field Has Required Attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I want to check if a `textarea` field has the `required` attribute for validation purpose. When user click on submit, it will pop up the loading image. I want to make sure the image is hidden after it shows the validation message. Below are the codes,

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="title" style="width:100%; name="title" required></textarea>
```

**jQUERY**

```
$("#submit").on("click",function() {
    $("#loading").css("display", "block"); //display the image 
    return true;
});
```

May I know how to check if the `required` is `true`, the loading image will be hidden. I tried to do like below but with fail result.

```
$("#submit").on("click",function() {
    $("#loading").css("display", "block");
    return true;

    if ($("#title").prop("required",true)) {
        $("#loading").css("display", "none"); 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#submit").on("click",function() {
   if ($("#title").val() != '') {
        $("#loading").css("display", "none"); 
    }
    else {
        $("#loading").css("display", "block");
        setTimeout(function(){ $('#loading').fadeOut() }, 5000); 
    } 

});
</script>
```

How many seconds that image should display. I kept for five seconds.

Comment: **Thanks for the help**. Like as I want it to be

Answer (score 1):

You are [updating the required property instead get it using `prop(''required)`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName).

```
if ($("#title").prop("required")) {
   $("#loading").css("display", "none"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `required` is a property you can use `.prop()` as getter *(when single argument)* with combination of `.toggle(condition)`:

```
$("#submit").on("click",function() {
    $("#loading").toggle(!$("#title").prop("required"));
});
```

Here `.toggle(!true)` in case if there is `required` property then `!true` will cause to hide the element.